# AM3 pinless design?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-phenom, am3

is the Phenom X6 / AM3 motherboards a pinless design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both the socket and the chip use µPGA technology.

[source](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.1&product=2.1.15&contentType=Tech+Doc+Processor&ostype=&keywords=&items=20)